# Points in a rectangle All

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to get all list of points to populate a boolean true if the list of points fall within a rectangle.

I've tried to run the below code in Jupyterlab. but I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

```
def allIn(firstCorner=(0,0), secondCorner=(0,0), pointList=[]):
   fc1,sc1=firstCorner[0],firstCorner[1]
   fc2,sc2=secondCorner[0],secondCorner[1]

   fc,sc=pointList[0],pointList[1]
   if (fc >= fc1 and fc <= fc2 and sc >= sc1 and sc <= sc2) :
       return True
   elif(fc >= fc2 and fc <= fc1 and sc >= sc2 and sc <= sc1):
       return True
   else:
       return False

print(allIn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,5)]))
```

I expect the output to be `allIn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,5)])` should return `True` but `allIn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,6)])` should return `False`
and empty list of points `allIn((0,0), (5,5), [])` should return `False`

Answer (score 0):

Your pointsList is a list of tuples. You have set

```
fc,sc=pointList[0],pointList[1]
```

So fc and sc are tuples. When you do

```
if (fc >= fc1 and fc <= fc2 and sc >= sc1 and sc <= sc2) :
```

You are comparing fc (a tuple) to fc1 (an int), which will throw a TypeError. To make the correct comparison look at pointList[0][0], pointList[0][1], pointList[1][0], etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look at individual points inside your list of points.

```
def allIn(firstCorner=(0,0), secondCorner=(0,0), pointList=[]):
   fc1,sc1=firstCorner[0],firstCorner[1]
   fc2,sc2=secondCorner[0],secondCorner[1]
   inside = False
   for point in pointList:
       fc,sc=point[0],point[1]
       if (fc >= fc1 and fc <= fc2 and sc >= sc1 and sc <= sc2) :
           inside = True
       elif(fc >= fc2 and fc <= fc1 and sc >= sc2 and sc <= sc1):
           inside = True
       else:
           return False
   return inside
```